# Spin dependence of wavefunction of meson states bound by a certain potential

Tags: particle-physics, harmonic-oscillator, quarks, mesons

Lets assume two spin half particles, for example a charm quark and a charm anti-quark are bound by a spherical harmonic oscillator potential to form bound meson states. The possible ground state configurations are vector state, known as the J/psi particle, and the other is the pseudoscalar state, known as the eta_c particle.
My question is, is there any way to consider the spin dependence of the resulting meson states, while writing the bound state radial wavefunction of the meson states?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the sort of thing your instructor has presumably drilled into you doggedly:

The spin-singlet $\eta_c$ is an $^1S_0$ state that should remind you of orthopositronium, so with $J^{PC}= 0^{-+}$.

By contrast, the spin-triplet *J/ψ* is $^3S_1$ reminding you of parapostironium, so with $J^{PC}= 1^{--}$.

The reason, as you recall, is  $P=(-)^{L+1}$ and   $C=(-)^{L+S}$, but here they are both s-wave, so *L=0*. The spins dictate that the triplet is spin symmetric and the singlet antisymmetric.